# Issue with using rmate on visual studio code - Unable to connect to TextMate on localhost:52698

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server, openssh, vscode-remote

I'm trying to create a remote connection with my server thru Visual Studio Code, I'm using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelmaiolla.remote-vscode extension. I set everything up, edited a user settings and used command `SSH 52698:localhost:52698`, It's worth mention that I'm using a VPS, so it's no so easy to manage it. While running last command which is `rmate`, I'm getting this error
`root@/fxxx:~# code file.txt /usr/local/bin/code: connect: Connection refused /usr/local/bin/code: line 412: /dev/tcp/localhost/52698: Connection refused Unable to connect to TextMate on localhost:52698`

I cant find a solution for this, and https://github.com/sclukey/rmate-python/issues/2 is not helping. Is there any solution for this problem?